# Highchart line chart Tooltip showing index value instead of X-axis formatted label name

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

My Problem of alignment is resolved with [Highcharts graph should start entirely to the left and end entirely to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616706/highcharts-graph-should-start-entirely-to-the-left-and-end-entirely-to-the-right)

But the tooltip information shown with index instead of x-axis label.

Without calling **`Highcharts.Axis.prototype.init`** below is the output?

```
http://jsfiddle.net/mkpasala/3s0prgau/
```

When I called the **`Highcharts.Axis.prototype.init`** method like below, instead of xAxis label its showing index.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/mkpasala/k94cfn8t/
```

Please help me to fix this inside **`Highcharts.Axis.prototype.init`** method.

Comment: Could you be more precise? What exactly you're going to achieve? Perhaps try to use `tooltip.formatter' function - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter.

Comment: Once I execute Highcharts.Axis.prototype.init method, the tooltip is getting overwritten with index value in place of x-axis label. please look at the two links you will understand the difference @WojciechChmiel

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by taking categories into a variable before calling **Highcharts.Axis.prototype.init** and used tooltip.formatter function to format the tooltip. Below is the link to that solution.

```
jsfiddle.net/mkpasala/3s0prgau/14/
```